# Magento : Get RETURNED/EXCHANGED Items List From Database

Tags: magento-1.9, product, magento-1, reports, items

I would like to build a report in Magento admin, where I can see all  products that have been returned or exchanged.

Does anyone know how to get a list of all the returned/exchanged products from a Magento database?